# Unable to turn on (toggle) the bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

Output of sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth

```
 [sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
\[    2.879585\] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
\[    2.880291\] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
\[    2.880292\] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
\[    2.880784\] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
\[    2.880788\] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
\[    2.880791\] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
\[    3.535905\] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
\[    3.535907\] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
\[    3.535911\] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
\[    4.974908\] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
\[  174.956508\] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110][1]
```

Output of systemctl status bluetooth.service

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-05-28 10:46:35 IST; 3min 46s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 747 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18150)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 24ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─747 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 28 10:46:35 G14 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 28 10:46:35 G14 bluetoothd[747]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
May 28 10:46:35 G14 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 28 10:46:35 G14 bluetoothd[747]: Starting SDP server
May 28 10:46:35 G14 bluetoothd[747]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 3277:0018 Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e0f6 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. Aluminium Keyboard (ANSI)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

sudo dmesg | grep -i firm
[sudo] password for utsav: 
[    0.076592] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.245473] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.843767] ACPI: video: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    3.655768] mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20221227123243
```

Comment: What result from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i firm`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have updated the question description with the same

Comment: What kernel is being used? `uname -r`  You should probably file a bug report as this device isn't in the newest kernels but I might be able to get it going with a change to the source code

Comment: @Jeremy31 my system is running on 5.19.0-43-generic

Answer (score 0):

First check `mokutil --sb` as Secure Boot must be disabled if Ubuntu is installed in EUFI
Then in terminal

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.19.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-5.19
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0
```

Reboot

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm. If possible, please let me know what was the reason it wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: Additionally, my brightness slider isn't working, could you please assist me with that too? I am running Nvidia 530 driver on a 4060 laptop (Asus G14 GA402XV 2023 model)

Comment: As I said, your Bluetooth wasn't supported even in the newest kernel, my source code is patched with https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.19/commit/3020823182dd74ca9c169eeb3d058908357b8452 and that is what made it work.  Start a new question for the brightness slider as I am not familiar with Nvidia